# Iphone 5s good to pokemon go?

Tags: pokemon-go

Hey guys ive been thinking of buying a new smartphone and i want one that can play pokemon go perfectly and im thinking of iphone 5s,is it good for pokemon go?i have some doubts because people say needs 2gb ram and this iphone only has 1gb and im also worried about it getting outdated soon,can you help me,thanks

Comment: If you buy a 1Gb phone, you basically have no storage lol.

Comment: He means RAM, not hard drive space, rather different things.

Comment: @PrivatePansy Not really i know the smartphone can play pokemon go I just wanna know if it plays it the possible best Thanks

Comment: @KevinTian So can you help? me thx

Comment: If you're concerned with your phone being outdated soon, you should consider buying a model that's not already 3 years old.

Comment: Flagging this question as off-topic because it's mostly opinion based.

Comment: @phantom42 maybe I dont have money for an iphone 6s xd

Answer (score 0):

I would try running the game on your iPhone to see how well it works. If the game runs well then stick with it and if it lags then maybe it is time to upgrade. Since your phone does meet the minimum requirements of the game I would not worry about it too much. If the game itself runs well now then it will have no problem running the game in the future.

Comment: The thing is that i didnt bought the iphone yet,Im still thinking about it

Comment: The phone will run pokemon go well. I have friends who have iPhone 5S and it works well. As for the other aspects you're worried about I cannot answer.

Comment: So it has the same  quality of gameplay such as an samsung galaxy edge 7 or iphone 6s plus?

Comment: That I cannot say for sure. Those phones will probably run the game more quickly but whether or not it's significantly noticeable I do not know.

Comment: Do you recomend this smartphone or another one in the same price range with a especiall attention to pokemon go?Thanks for the help

Comment: I have never owned an iPhone before and I don't want to affect your decision on which phone to buy only to have you regret it later. I will say this, pokemon go will definitely run well on iPhone 5S as well as the majority of other games.